# Calculating extreme spread with a Do loop

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to model what is called the extreme spread of a series of shots at a target. Each shot is from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1. For this example there are three shots per group and I have four groups to analyze.

The computation of the extreme spread is simply the maximum [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the shots, so I need to compute all of the Euclidean distances between the three shots per group. Then find the maximum distance for each group.

The following code attempts to do that except the last step (the `do` loop) doesn't work. I'm new to Mathematica, so I'm not even sure my syntax is correct - except that Mathematica doesn't return an error.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
μ = 0
σ = 1
RandomSeed[66936, Method -> All];
\[ScriptCapitalD] = NormalDistribution[μ, σ];
rv := RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD]];
shotsPerGroup = 3
iterations = 4
data = Flatten[Table[List[i, rv], {i, 1, iterations}, {j, 1, shotsPerGroup}], 1];
groupBy = GatherBy[data, First][[All, All, 2]];

edist = {}
Do[
  Append[edist, EuclideanDistance[groupBy[[i, j]], groupBy[[i, k]]]],
  {i, 1, iterations},
  {j, i, shotsPerGroup - 1},
  {k, j + 1, shotsPerGroup}
]
edist
```

Comment: Look up `AppendTo`.

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/29734) (and other pitfalls in that thread).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 11):

More Mathematica-ish

```
SeedRandom[42];
mu = 0;
sigma = 1;
shotsPerGroup = 3;
iterations = 4;
rv = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], {iterations, shotsPerGroup, 2}];
pairs = Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ rv;
Max /@ Apply[EuclideanDistance, pairs, {2}]
(*
 {1.29553, 3.05122, 1.24002, 2.10169}
*)
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code is almost completely correct, but I did notice your use of
    Append
which actually doesn't reassign the value of edist, for that, you would to use     AppendTo.